# Convert all column headers into regressors in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-columns

I'm completely new to R and would like to turn each column label (header?) in my data set into a regressor without having to define each regressor one at a time, i.e. date -> data$Date

Is there a way to do this all at once?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post a simple reproducible example? And what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
R > data(iris)
R > head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
R > lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)        Sepal.Width       Petal.Length        Petal.Width
           2.1713             0.4959             0.8292            -0.3152
Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica
          -0.7236            -1.0235
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose specific column you can use this:

data is `sample.data` with dependent variable in `col 3` and `cols 1, 2, 4:8` are independent variables

```
 yy<-lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(sample.data)[3], "~",paste(colnames(sample.data)[c(1, 2,4:8)], collapse = "+"), sep = "")), data=sample.data)
    )
 summary(yy)
```